# Rails 3 Nested Models unknown attribute Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, railscasts

- I have a model "Issue" and a nested Model "Relationship"
- In the issue.rb I have mentioned:

  ```
  has_many :relationships, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :relationships, :allow_destroy => true
  ```
- In relationship.rb I have mentioned:

  ```
  belongs_to :issue
  ```
- Following Ryan Bates Railcast#196 I have the following in my issues_controller:

  ```
  relationship = @issue.relationships.build
  ```

However, I am encountering an error "unknown attribute: relationship"

Am I doing something incorrectly here? I do see the Relationships Attributes being passed to the server in the log however, this error does not let the create to be successful.

My expertise with rails is beginners level so kindly excuse me if I am asking a question which maybe deemed trivial.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**: The relevant Controller code:

```
    @relationship = @issue.relationships.build
    #@relationship = Relationship.new(params[:relationship])
    if @relationship.issue_id = ''
      @relationship.issue_id = @issueid
    end

    if @relationship.cause_id = ''
      @relationship.cause_id = @issueid
    end

    @relationship.save
    redirect_to(:back, :notice => 'New Relationship was created')
```

What I see on the trace:

```
    ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in IssuesController#create
    unknown attribute: relationship
```

Among the Issue parameters, I see the Relationship params being passed as expected:

```
    "relationship"=>{"issue_id"=>"100",
    "cause_id"=>""}
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**
Posting the form_for code:

```
    - form_for Issue.new do |f|

      .field  
        = f.text_field :description, :class=>"formfield", :id=>"frm_descr"

      .field  
        = f.hidden_field :wiki_url, :class=>"formfield", :id=>"frm_wiki_url"

      .field
        = f.hidden_field :short_url, :class=>"formfield", :id=>"frm_img_url"

      .field
        = f.hidden_field :title, :class=>"formfield", :id=>"frm_title"         

      = f.fields_for :relationship do |builder|
        = builder.text_field :issue_id, :class=>"form_field", :id=>"frm_rel_issue_id", :value=>@issue.id 
        = builder.text_field :cause_id, :class=>"form_field", :id=>"frm_rel_cause_id"

      .actions
        = f.submit 'Create', :class=>"save_button", :name=>"save_issue_rel_button", :id=>"val_collector"
```

Comment: Add your complete controller action please and perhaps provide a stack trace to showing where the error is occurring.

Comment: @Thilo: Edited the question to include relevant controller code and trace.

Comment: What should be passed to your IssuesController#create method is not "relationship", but a "relationship_attributes" hash. Are you using fields_for as the screencast shows?

Comment: @Thilo: Just posted another EDIT to include the Form_for code Im using.

Comment: @Ryan: The rails documentation also points out that the parameters for nested attributes should be passed to server as an attribute hash i.e. relationship_attributes => { :blah => 'blah' } in this case. We see this is not happening. How can I correct this to be passed as an attribute hash instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this line

```
= f.fields_for :relationship do |builder|
```

to this:

```
= f.fields_for :relationships do |builder|
```

Your issue has_many relationships - plural. That will give you the correct relationships_attributes parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the working skeleton code:
I created a new project and tried the combination of the other answers, and finally made it to work.

Here is my solution, after that are the things to watch out for. I am using different models so bear with me:

- My models are: **discussion** has_many **posts**.
- **Discussion** has no attributes.
- **Posts** has content:text and discussion_id:integer.

### Working Code

(model) discussion.rb

```
has_many :posts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
```

(model) post.rb

```
belongs_to :discussion
```

routes.rb

```
resources :discussions do
  resources :posts
end
```

(discussion view) _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@discussion) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :posts, @post do |p| %>
    <%= p.text_area :content %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

(controller) discussions_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @discussion = Discussion.new
    @post = @discussion.posts.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @discussion }
    end
  end

  def create
    @discussion = Discussion.new(params[:discussion])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @discussion.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@discussion, :notice => 'Discussion was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @discussion, :status => :created, :location => @discussion }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @discussion.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

---

### Possible things that can go wrong

First, Thilo was right, I get *unknown attribute: post* if I do

```
# WRONG!
f.fields_for :post
```

Second, I have to have the @post instance variable in **new** action otherwise the post.context textarea will not show up.

```
# REQUIRED!
@post = @discussion.posts.build
```

Third, If I use the **f.fields_for @post**, the create action will complain *unknown attribute: post* too.

```
# WRONG!
f.fields_for @post do |p|
```

Use this instead:

```
# RIGHT!
f.fields_for :posts, @post  do |p|
```

---

### The End

So yeah, I wish we get to see more documentations on this (can't see any useful ones). For example I see some use of form_for [@discussion, @post] but I can never get it to work.

Comment: Undeleted pending an edit by the poster into something more of an answer instead of a discussion about things that was tried.

Comment: thanks! the `.build` did the trick for creating both parent and child in the same form.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are constructing the relationship in your controller and then trying to use it in the view. In order for this to be visible, you must make it an *instance variable*. All you need to do is throw an @ symbol in from of the name of `relationship`, as you have done with `@issue`.

```
@relationship = @issue.relationships.build
```

Edit: due to further information provided by the OP after the original question was asked, this answer is now clearly not applicable.

Comment: That should make no difference if the relationship variable is scoped only to the relevant action.

Comment: @Jeremy: Thanks for the answer but even after doing this I am getting the same Error. Could you please suggest why this might be happening?

Comment: I don't think this is the real fix for it. `@relationship` is not referenced in the view anywhere.

Comment: Thilo: The view logic was originally not provided; I'd assumed that the name "relationship" was being used in the view as well, in which case it would not be found.

Ryan: you're correct. My previous diagnosis was based on the original information

Answer (score 0):

By using accepts_nested_attributes, you have created a setter method relationship_attributes=.

There are a couple of things I noticed that need to change.

You don't need to set

```
@relationship = @issue.relationships.build
```

Your form should be the following (you have f.fields_for :relationship)

```
= form_for @issue do |f|

  # your issue fields here

  = f.fields_for :relationships do |r|

    # your relationship fields here
```

The beauty here is that you won't have to set any ids or anything.

Comment: No, it should be `f.fields_for`, otherwise they will just be fields out in the open.

Comment: @Ryan: So if I do not set @relationship = @issue.relationship.build in the controller, I get the "undefined method `relationship' for #<Class:0x8228cb8>" Error. Kindly guide me.