# Why does this select field appear multiple times in my Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I've got a Rails application that is using nested forms. Details follow and I tried this solution ([Rails 3 Nested Models unknown attribute Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838297/rails-3-nested-models-unknown-attribute-error)), but for some reason, the field is repeating multiple times instead of listing and saving the options correctly. Thanks in advance for your help!

**Model information for Newsavedmaps**

```
has_many :waypoints, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :waypoints
```

**Newsavedmap_controller**

```
def new
  @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.new
  waypoint = @newsavedmap.waypoints.build
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @newsavedmap }
  end
end

def edit
  @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.find(params[:id])
  if @newsavedmap.itinerary.user_id == current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # edit.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @activity }
    end  
  else
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

**Maptry View**

```
<% form_for @newsavedmap, :html=>{:id=>'createaMap'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <% f.fields_for :waypoint do |w| %>
    <%= w.select :waypointaddress, options_for_select(Waypoint.find(:all, :conditions => {:newsavedmap_id => params[:newsavedmap_id]}).collect {|wp| [wp.waypointaddress, wp.waypointaddress] }), {:include_blank => true}, {:multiple => true, :class => "mobile-waypoints-remove", :id =>"waypoints"} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I use the above code, my form works correctly, but submitting it gives me this error:

```
UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: waypoint)
```

When I change ":waypoint do |w|" to ":waypoints do |w|" in the view, the select field disappears when the user is creating a new record, and in the edit view, the select field appears several times (however many waypoints the user saved in the record.)

How can I get this form field to work properly?

**EDIT 1**

Here is my latest attempt. For new records, the select field does not appear. However, in the edit view, the select field appears multiple times. This is a Rails 2 application, FYI. Taking a cue from the comments, I used a collection_select approach (not collection_for_select because I couldn't find documentation for that.) Again, I appreciate your help!

```
    <% f.fields_for :waypoints do |w| %> 
        <%= w.collection_select( :waypointaddress, @newsavedmap.waypoints, :waypointaddress, :waypointaddress, {:include_blank => true}, {:id =>"waypoints"} ) %>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: First things first. If the name of the association is `waypoints`, then you **have to** use `f.fields_for :waypoints do |w|`. Of course you don't have an attribute named `waypoint` because that's not the name of the association.

Comment: Now what exactly do you mean by "the select field disappears"? That doesn't sound like a Rails issue.

Comment: Thanks, depa, but when I do that, the select field disappears when the user is creating a new record, and in the edit view, the select field appears several times (however many waypoints the user saved in the record.) By disappears, I mean that the select field does not show up in the source code for a new record or in the browser display. However, it appears several times in the edit view. Again, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, I read it and it doesn't help if you repeat it, because it didn't help me the first time. Are you using JavaScript to create new selects or something like that?

Comment: Also, since you have a problem in the edit view, please post the content of your edit action in the controller.

Comment: There are three fields. There's a multi select field that is my actual fields_for (waypoints). Then, there's another multi select field (selectbox). Users can select options in addbox, click a button, and create them as options in the waypoints select using javascript. Finally, there's an input box users can use to add options to waypoints (inputbox). Added edit code above.

Comment: The waypoints multi select field that uses fields_for begins with zero waypoints inside of it, but it should at least have a blank option.

Comment: And this form you posted is exactly the same one you're using for both `#new` and `#edit`?

Comment: I've eliminated the fields for the @newsavedmap part of the form above, but the form_for part is a duplicate from my code. I don't know if it matters, but this is a Rails 2 app.

Comment: Try using `w.collection_select` instead of `w.select`.

Comment: Error `TemplateError ({:class=>"mobile-waypoints-remove", :id=>"waypoints", :multiple=>true} is not a symbol)`

Comment: Did you just use the same arguments? The API for `collection_select` is a bit different.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37025/discussion-between-kdp-and-depa)

Answer (score 0):

Your form has the following problems.

1. Use `f.fields_for :waypoints` since the argument needs to match the name of the association.
2. Use [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) rather than `select`, since you have an ActiveRecord model behind that field.

So, taking that into account, you could try this for your form:

```
<% form_for @newsavedmap, :html => { :id => 'createaMap' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <% f.fields_for :waypoints do |w| %>
    <%= w.collection_for_select :waypoint, :waypointaddress, @newsavedmap.waypoints, :waypointaddress, :waypointaddress, { :include_blank => true }, { :multiple => true, :class => "mobile-waypoints-remove", :id =>"waypoints" } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The API for `collection_select` is a bit tricky to get right. I usually need a few attempts as well. This previous SO question may help clear things up: [Can someone explain collection_select to me in clear, simple terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907867/can-someone-explain-collection-select-to-me-in-clear-simple-terms)

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. Unfortunately, when I tried the code above, the select field does not appear when the user is creating a new record or when the user is editing a record.